# How to create facebook application for a group

Tags: php, facebook

I am a php web programmer. I don't have much experience in facebook application. I have a facebook group of 42 people. all are my friends. I want to build an application for this group only. Only the group member will have permission to access the application. When a member visits the group page, he will see the application and use it. How can I do this?

I do know a little about facebook application. I have a personal hosting which I will use to host program files and mysql database. But I want a basic guideline. Please tell me from scratch. If anyone know a online documentation or guideline, please mention the link. Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unfortunately, I don't have the time right now to help you with a complete guide, but here's the main idea:

Make a [facebook app](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/guides/canvas/) that asks the user for the [user_groups permissions](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/permissions/).

With this permission, you can see the groups the user is a part of. Then, you can simply check to see if YOUR group is among them. If it is... super! show him the content. If not, show him a blank page, an error page or whatever, it's totally up to you.

Some other helpful links are these: [Facebook PHP references](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/php) and [Facebook JavaScript references](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/javascript/).